Connecting Apache kafka on AWS with Spark on GCP
I have set up a Dataproc cluster on GCP to run spark jobs and the spark job resides on a GCS bucket that I have already provisioned. Separately, I have setup kafka on AWS by setting up a MSK cluster and an EC2 instance which has kafka downloaded on it.
This is part of a larger architecture in which we want to run multiple microservices and use kafka to send files from those microservices to the spark analytical service on GCP for data processing and send results back via kafka.
However I am unable to understand how to connect kafka with spark. I dont understand how they will be able to communicate since they are on different cloud providers. The internet is giving me very vague answers since this is a very specific situation.
Please guide me on how to resolve this issue.
PS: I'm a cloud newbie :)

It's not a specific situation... What issue? Where's your code? What error are you getting? https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

The connection will transverse the internet... The main difference between your home/office network and "another cloud" is the firewall settings would be separate
You'd connect with the public MSK ports
BTW, you can run Kafka in GCP as well... You could also use Dataflow (i.e. Apache Beam), not Spark
